# Не могу создать триггер в котором имя вызываемой функции хранится в переменной

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток, возникла проблема: в зависимости от id изменнённой записи необходимо вызвать определённую функцию MySQL, делаю триггер.

Вот код триггера:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER price_change 
 after 
update ON `cms_flower`.oc_product 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @func varchar(10); 
SET @func = 'Call ' + NEW.product_id + '(' + NEW.price + ')';  
exec(@func);  
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Выдаёт:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@func
>   varchar(10);  SET @func = 'Call' + NEW.product_id + '(' + NEW.price +
>   ')'' at line 5

Не знаю как реализовать, помогите пжлст

Comment: а это точно [tag:mysql], а не [tag:mariadb]?

Comment: @NickVolynkin это MariaDB, но она MySQL-совместима по большей части. Видимо, ТСа интересует как раз MySQL-совместимый набор фич. Так что набор меток очень даже осмысленный.

Comment: @D-side ок, спасибо. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызываемая функция имеет то же имя, что содержится в `product_id`?

```
SET @q = CONCAT('CALL ', NEW.product_id, '(', NEW.price, ')');
PREPARE s FROM @q;
EXECUTE s;
```

Answer (score 0):

@func - это пользовательская переменная, нужно
DECLARE func varchar(10);

Используйте подготовленные выражения prepare/execute